# How to make common var?

Tags: c#

Hi guys a have a code­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool od_auth(string login, string pass)
        {
            var cook­ies = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;

            if (response.Headers["Location"] != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;

            }
        }

        public bool od_info_changer()
        {
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            if (response.Headers["Location"].IndexOf("st.cmd=userSettings") != -1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        private void Auth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string login = textBox1.Text;
            string pass = textBox2.Text;
            bool avt = od_auth(login, pass);
            bool change = od_info_changer();
            if (avt == true)
            {

            }
            else
            {
            }
            if (change == true)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have to­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ use in `"public bool od_info_changer()"` the var cookies from `public bool od_auth(string login, string pass)`.
How can I do it?­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Next time you should show what you have tried, because we don't want to do your work ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `var` in this case and make cookies a field:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private CookieContainer cookies;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool od_auth(string login, string pass)
        {
            cook­ies = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;

            if (response.Headers["Location"] != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;

            }
        }

        public bool od_info_changer()
        {
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            if (response.Headers["Location"].IndexOf("st.cmd=userSettings") != -1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        private void Auth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string login = textBox1.Text;
            string pass = textBox2.Text;
            bool avt = od_auth(login, pass);
            bool change = od_info_changer();
            if (avt == true)
            {

            }
            else
            {
            }
            if (change == true)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cookies` is not *global*. It's a member variable/field of the class.

Comment: @DominicKexel: Yeah, just've seen it after posting, already edited. But thanks :).

Comment: Your answer is right of course, it just bugs me everytime when I hear *global variable* in C# :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use a field or a property :

[Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) :

```
private CookieType cookie;
```

[Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) :

```
private CookieType cookie { get; set; }
```

the value will become visible inside the object

Answer (score 0):

Just move your variables up to the class level and declare them inside the class but right before the constructor for your form. All the methods in your class will have access to them then.